# Natively override core extension classes from templates?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, mvc, joomla-3.6

Is there any way to do this natively yet (ie. without using a plugin)? I'm hoping there's native support similar to the way the old MVC Override plugin allowed class overrides using a /code folder in the templates directory (much like how template HTML overrides currently work). All the documentation on it is fairly out of date so I figured it's worth asking, but I'm sure I'm out of luck.

All I want to do is swap out a few items on the quickicons module and I need to override its helper class to do so - writing a system plugin or having to make a custom version of the module seems a touch overkill.

Comment: Please check this links: 1- https://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/521-did-you-know-overrides-are-not-just-for-html.html 2- https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: That second link is what I meant by out of date documentation.

As I thought, the answer is still no. Cheers anyway.

Comment: Answer is "no". And also I believe this a bad idea. I mean override is great. Override code with template is bad simply because template should be last execution point and any thing, for example component can change current template on fly.

Comment: I can see why it's a bad idea, and definitely shouldn't be used by anyone actually publishing templates for public use, so I can get why it's not implemented. It's still a bit of an inconvenience when you control everything going on from top to bottom and just want to very slightly change a module's behaviour though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no core MVC override support.

At the doc you say is outdated https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core
there is a link to a working plugin [MVC override](http://gruz.org.ua/en/extensions/mvcoverride.html) (well, mine one).

Comment: I believe this is the usual way to go about it.  Another option if you want to change quick icons you could just copy it, rename it and develop it as you like and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download my custom quick icon module and create your own links.
[JoomIcon](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/administration/joomicon/)